# Badge progress - 305/300 - Civic Duty

Tags: feature-request, bug, badge-progress

Why not remove a badge from the Badge Progress popout on [Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts) when the badge has been awarded?

[image: Bug]

Comment: Wait for the badge script...

Comment: @Mysticial Badge has already been given...

Comment: Then what's the bug?

Comment: @Mysticial Shouldn't this row disappear?

Comment: Why would it need to? If it ain't broke don't fix it?

Comment: @Mysticial So it "looks nicer"? :p

Comment: It's not really a bug if the numbers are correct.

Comment: @WesleyMurch That much is true. I'll edit my question.

Comment: Where even is this popout? Oh, I see it. I had no idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically because it's fun seeing all those bars filled.

I argue it looks nice enough, there's no need to fix it.